# NSURLConnection in Swift: How to call a function when it's finished loading, and restart it if the URL is a 404?

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

I am using Google Image API to generate images like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=seattle")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){ (response, go, error) -> Void in            
let go = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(go, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as [String:AnyObject]
let responseData = go["responseData"] as [String:AnyObject]
```

Then the rest of code digs down to find the URL of the image google api gives and sets (var theurl here) the image in the app to that:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: theurl!)
self.mainImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

This works but I need 1) to stop the process and call a function if it finds an image URL that it can't load and 2) call a function when the image has finished loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues here that need to be addressed. I think it will make more sense to walk through an example. The following is your exact same logic, just slightly more robust.

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainImage: UIImageView!
    let operationQueue: NSOperationQueue = {
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4
        queue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfService.Utility

        return queue
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadImage { [weak self] image in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                if let image = image {
                    strongSelf.mainImage.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func downloadImage(completion: UIImage? -> Void) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=seattle")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: self.operationQueue) { [weak self] response, data, error in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                if error != nil || data == nil {
                    println(error) // failed to complete original google api request
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }

                var serializationError: NSError?
                if let go = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments, error: &serializationError) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    let responseData = go["responseData"] as [String:AnyObject]
                    let imageURL = NSURL(string: "some_image_url_from_response_data")! // placeholder
                    let imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: strongSelf.operationQueue) { response, data, error in
                        if error != nil || data == nil {
                            println(error) // failed to download the image
                            completion(nil)
                            return
                        }

                        if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            completion(image)
                        } else {
                            println("Failed to create UIImage from downloaded image data")
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println(serializationError)
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Asynchronous Operation Queue**

First off, you were making an asynchronous request on the main queue which defeats the whole purpose of async behavior. Instead, I made a concurrent operation queue property which is used to handle the download operations.

**Weakify / Strongify**

Anytime you are doing asynchronous things, you have to be VERY careful about retaining `self`. The safest way to guarantee you always do it properly is to weakify / strongify to avoid creating a retain cycle.

**Nested Async Request**

You should use another `sendAsynchronousRequest` call to download the image in the background. Otherwise you will block the main thread while you download the image. Your users would not be happy with that behavior!

**Safe Deserialization**

It's pretty important to check that your JSON parsing is successful. Servers can do some odd things sometimes, and your code should be able to handle that without any issues.

**Alamofire**

Have you taken a look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)? It makes things like this much MUCH easier.

Hopefully that helps shed some light.

Comment: thanks, I'll go over that. I've just started learning about API's and swift/JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use the completion-block and check the `NSError` you get.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if let theError = error{
       if theError.code == 404{
        //Image not available
       }else{
        //something else
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: Do I copy and paste that while also keeping my original "NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){ (response, go, error) -> Void in" line? Also with the queue: queue I get a "use of unresolved identifier 'queue'" error, should I put "var queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()" at the top and then do queue: self.queue?

Comment: That is a sample Code. You have to edit it that it works for you. But you need to use that instead of your method.

Comment: Note that this will crash if no error occurs since error will be nil.